# different languages with different syntaxcheck in same visual studio code file

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to have different syntax highlighting in different sections in the same file in visual studio code?

I mix classic asp, html and js in the same file.

in asp, everything after a single quote is a comment, in js it delimits a string.

Is there some way I can tel vscode that this part is asp, and this part is js?

Comment: you have to create a new language definition and mark the blocks as having a particular syntax

Comment: Could you elaborate on "mark the blocks as having a particular syntax" This is in the visual studio code editor, not markup on this page.

Comment: write the language definition file, here you specify the blocks and there language type

Comment: You mean I can specify that everything is html except that <% %> delimits asp and <script></script> delimits js when the filename is *.asp ?

Comment: yes, I have seen an example a few questions ago

Comment: I failed to locate it :-(

Comment: what does the doc say about the language def file

Comment: You probably want me to find and decode the information myself instead of just telling me. but I failed to do so.

Comment: loosely related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76334033/11107541