# VSCode - is it possible to have different Language modes in the same file

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to have different Language modes in the same file?

I have a sample code C/C# and in one string constant there is an SQL code, like the following:

```
/*
 Sample SQL statement:
        select
            id      as PersonID,
            [name]  as PersonName
        from
            tABC
        WHERE
            id > 50
             AND
            name like N'%john%'
        ;
*/

int main() {
    printf(@"
        select
            id      as PersonID,
            [name]  as PersonName
        from
            tABC
        WHERE
            id > 50
             AND
            name like N'%john%'
        ;
    ");
    return 0;
}
```

The file is in the C/C# language mode, and all the syntactic components of C code are colored in the right way.

I would like (if it is possible) to have the SQL part of the code (which is actually just a string in the outside C code and part of the comment) to be formatted as SQL language mode.

[Actual VSCode rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48JBx.gif)

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5N4Km.gif)

The version of the VSCode I am using is 1.87.2 (user setup)

I tried to select part of the SQL code and do a Ctrl-K, Ctrl-F
it did not work - syntax highlighting stayed the same - as a string in C, and not a SQL command

Then I tried ALt+Shift+F
the same results

Then, with selected text, I tried to change Select Language Mode from C to SQL, but the changes applied to the whole file, not to the selected part

I tried to find answer on Google, but could not describe my problem sufficiently well.

Then I went to ChatGPT, and again no satisfactory answer.

I found the similar question [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70795399/different-languages-with-different-syntaxcheck-in-same-visual-studio-code-file), but with no answer (there are some comments, actually).

Comment: It's possible if you make your own C# syntax extension replacing the stock one (which is just a bunch of regexes used to parse the language for syntax highlighting). Won't be an easy task though. And it has to automatically decide which strings to highlight as SQL.

Comment: I do not expect for VSCode to understand what type of code it is, I would change it manually - so I select a part of code, and apply language mode for this part.

Comment: Then you need to write a custom extension (something more complicated than a bunch of regexes I suggested previously).

Comment: So, if I understood you well, you say it is NOT possible to do it in VSCode (easy, user-friendly, without-coding way).

Comment: Yes, as far as I know.

Comment: you must write a TextMate grammar and inject the foreign language grammar, you must some how be able to decide which part of the file has the different grammar

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Write it as an answer, so I can accept it, and thank you.

Comment: IMO a proper answer would explain how to make/find an extension for it, I don't want to post just "impossible without an extension".

Comment: please don't post a question again if you know that it is a duplicate.